# Linked List Creating head causing error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: visual-c++, singly-linked-list

I am trying to make a linkedList but when I create a Head in a separate ADT with class Node Included in it it produces an error `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'`

This is code for ADT of Node

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    friend LinkedList;
protected:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(int d =-999, Node *n = NULL);

    //Mutators
    void setData(int d);
    void setNext(Node *n);

    //Accessors
    int getData ();
    Node *getNext();

};
```

This is code for ADT LinkedList

```
class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head; //This line is causing that particular error
public:
//some lines of code
};
```

I am completely lost tried every possible solution but can't figure out what's actually going wrong here.

Comment: It should be obvious what's going on - you are using the name `Node` before it was declared. You need to provide a forward declaration for it, or else `#include "Node.h"` However, if you do the latter, you need to remove `#include "LinkedList.h"` from `Node.h`, or else you will end up with circular includes. You don't need a full definition of a class just to declare it a friend.

Comment: So basically what my `LinkedList` class is doing it is getting declared but not finding a reference to ADT named Node. Thanks a lot, adding `class Node;` after my `LinkedList.h`'s directves sloved the problem.